# Unintended Flashing of Black and White

Tags: java, swing

I am honestly not sure why this is happening. The only "rendering" code in my java project, which at the moment is quite small, is the following:

```
public void render(){
        if (bs == null){
            bs = getBufferStrategy();
            if (bs == null){
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
        }
        g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

        bs.show();
        g2d.dispose();
    }
```

When I run my project, the frame flickers quickly between black and white. I don't even have code changing the background color nor the Graphics2D color.

Following this are the Engine and Window classes:

```
package io.shparki.cyberphunk;

import io.shparki.cyberphunk.gfx.Window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Engine extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 1200;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    public static final String TITLE = "Cyberphunk";
    public static final String VERSION = "Alpha v1.0.0";

    public static final int TARGET_UPS = 60;
    public static final long SECOND = 1_000_000_000L;
    public static final long PERIOD = SECOND / TARGET_UPS;
    private int currentUPS = 0, currentFPS = 0;
    private int UPS = 0, FPS = 0;
    private double deltaTime = 0;

    private volatile boolean running = false;
    private Thread animator;

    private Game game;
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics2D g2d;


    public Engine(){
        Window.create(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, this);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if (!running || animator == null){
            animator = new Thread(this, "Animator");
            animator.start();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public void run(){
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long beforeTime = currentTime;
        long upsCounter = 0, secCounter = 0;

        initialize();

        running = true;
        while (running){
            beforeTime = currentTime;
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaTime = currentTime - beforeTime;

            upsCounter += deltaTime;
            if (upsCounter >= PERIOD){
                upsCounter -= PERIOD;
                currentUPS ++;
                update();
            }

            currentFPS ++;
            render();

            secCounter += deltaTime;
            if (secCounter >= SECOND){
                secCounter -= SECOND;
                UPS = currentUPS; FPS = currentFPS;
                currentUPS = 0; currentFPS = 0;
                System.out.println("UPS: " + UPS + " | FPS: " + FPS);
                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public void initialize(){
            game = new Game();
        }
        public void update(){
            game.update();
        }
        public void render(){
            if (bs == null){
                bs = getBufferStrategy();
                if (bs == null){
                    createBufferStrategy(3);
                    return;
                }
            }
            g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

            bs.show();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

package io.shparki.cyberphunk.gfx;

import io.shparki.cyberphunk.io.Input;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window {
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static Canvas content;
    private static Input input;

    public static void create(int width, int height, String title, Canvas content){
        Window.content = content;
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        content.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        content.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        input = new Input();
        content.setFocusable(true);
        content.requestFocus();
        //content.addKeyListener(input);
        //content.addMouseListener(input);
        //content.addMouseMotionListener(input);
    }

    public static int getWidth() { return content.getWidth(); }
    public static int getHeight() { return content.getHeight(); }

    public static String getTitle() { return frame.getTitle(); }
    public static void setTitlte(String title) { frame.setTitle(title); }
}
```

Comment: Yep, its likely that one page is white and one page is black

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking, but I have written this code so many times before, its literally just broiler plate code. I changed one thing about 30 minutes ago, it did something weird so I deleted it, and now this is happening. I rewrote the entire engine and window classes and this is still happening. No other class even has access to render yet.

Comment: You will need to fill each page with the color you want, otherwise the Graphics context is "uninitialized" in the context of you will get what ever API defaulted to

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be disposing of the Graohics context, but I could be mistaken, but I'd personally do it before show, but that's me

Comment: Swing defaults to white. What should be happening, is the screen remains white until I tell it what to do. Instead it is switching between White and Black. Black is not a default to any value, so something must be setting it to Black and I don't understand what is.

Comment: But it's not Swing, it's AWT. Try removing g2d.dipose. There's also no need to maintain class level  instance reference of the Graphics